# Ionic2 How to scroll a list?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am using Ionic2.

I have a list of items. On an event (`messageSend` function called), I would like to scroll to the top of the list.

**messages.html**

```
<ion-content padding class="messages-page-content">
    <ion-scroll scrollY="true" class="messages">
  <ion-list class="message-list">
    <ion-item ....
```

**messages.ts**

```
messageSend(va, vi) {
  // scroll to top of list
}
```

Any advise appreciated.

**Update**

Here is some sample code:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
       <ion-avatar item-left class='menu-ion-avatar'><img src='{{you.avatar ? you.avatar : you.avatar64 ? you.avatar64 : you.avatarFirebase ? you.avatarFirebase : "images/blank-profile-picture.png"}}'></ion-avatar> 
        <div class='item-avatar-name'>{{you.displayName}}</div>
        <div class="title-timestamp">{{you.lastAccessDate | amDateFormat: 'D MMM YYYY h:mm a'}}</div>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding class="messages-page-content">
    <ion-scroll scrollY="true" class="messages">
  <ion-list class="message-list" id="message-list">
    <ion-item class="message-item" *ngFor="let item of firelist | async">
        <div [ngClass]="{'message message-me':(item.memberId1 == me.uid)}">
        <div [ngClass]="{'message message-you':(item.memberId1 == you.uid)}">
                    <div class="message-content">{{item.message_text}}</div>
                    <span class="time-tick">
                        <span class="message-timestamp-date">{{item.timestamp | amDateFormat: 'D MMM YY'}}</span>
                        <span class="message-timestamp">{{item.timestamp | amDateFormat: 'h:mm a'}}</span>
                        <div *ngIf="item.memberId1 === me.uid && item.readByReceiver === true">
                            <span class="checkmark">
                                <div class="checkmark_stem"></div>
                                <div class="checkmark_kick"></div>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
                </div>
        </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
    </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <form #f="ngForm">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col width-90>
          <ion-input [(ngModel)]="message" name="messageText" required placeholder="message..."></ion-input>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-10 center>
          <button (click)="messageSend(f.value, f.valid)" full [disabled]="f.valid === false"><ion-icon class="message-send" name="send"></ion-icon></button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </form>
</ion-footer>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the top of the list is also the top of the page, you can use the `scrollToTop()` method from the content instance like this:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage{
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

  scrollToTop() {
    this.content.scrollToTop();
  }
}
```

If not, you'll need to get the position of the element and use the `scrollTo(x,y,duration)` method, like this:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage {
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

  constructor() {   }

  public scrollElement() {
    let element = document.getElementById('target');
    this.content.scrollTo(0, element.offsetTop, 500);
  }
}
```

**[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zmp6NF?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you. But it doesn't seem to make any difference. Before I added the scrollToTop or scrollTo as you suggest, it was always scrolling up by default by the size of the item added to the list. If you are manually scrolled halfway down the list, then it leaves you there, but scrolls up by just one item. It seems to be doing the same now. is content the correct object to scroll on?

Comment: Could you please add some of the html code to the post? So I can create a plunker with it and we can work on that plunker to figure out what's going on

Comment: @Richard Thanks. I've created [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zmp6NF?p=preview) with a very simple demo using some basic items and the `scrollToTop()` method. Could you please check if this is the desired behaviour?

Comment: Thanks, your example works. Mine only works if I remove the  `<ion-scroll scrollY="true" class="messages">` tag.

Comment: Glad to hear that :) I was going to ask you about that because I'm not sure of what it does but great...